# how to export UI component to a string or something

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I'm working on dashboard editor in flex, an application that allow users to drag ui objects inside a canvas. i need a solution to save the canvas with the objects inside (with all properties and locations x & y) to allow users to save dashboards to database and to open them .
I need a way to get the canvas insides without parsing each object inside the canvas. some build-in function to export a ui object into mxml string or something.
I'm wondering if there is a way to do that.
regards,
Elad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll should use [this](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#getClassInfo()) function.
After you should go for each property and get parameter from your UIComponent, so at the end you'll serialize it to String as you want (so in 4-5 strings of code you'll make your export).

But I should to say that you'll have a problems when you'll parse it back, because:
**there are inherited read-only properties, which you can't apply for new instance manually!**

So you'll need to export e.g. {x:yourUIComponent.x,y:yourUIComponent.y,color:yourUIComponent.color}

Something like this, so there are no the code as you exactly want, but there are another way:

each user is generating events on your dashboard, if you'll save this events, you could recreate the components on other client sides, using event handlers that you already have.

Questions? :)